# An ellipse with major axis $4$ and minor axis $2$ touches both the coordinate axes. Locus of its Center and Focus is?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

An ellipse with major axis $4$ and minor axis $2$ touches both the coordinate axes. Locus of its Center and Focus is?

**My Approach:** **For locus of Center**.

Since it is touching the coordinate axes, the coordinate axes will act as tangents making angle of $90^{\circ}$, so origin will lies on Director Circle.

Center of director circle will be same as center of Ellipse.

Let center of Ellipse be $(h,k)$, so the equation of director circle will be $$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=(\text{semi major axis})^2+ (\text{semi minor axis})^2,$$

$$i.e.\;\;\;(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=(2)^2+ (1)^2.$$

Because it passes through the origin,

$(0-h)^2+(0-k)^2=(2)^2+ (1)^2$

$\implies $ $h^2+k^2=5$

$\implies $ locus of center of Ellipse is $x^2+y^2=5$.

**For Locus of Focus**:

I assumed focus as $(x_1,y_1)$ but i cannot proceed further. I know one property, that product of distance of tangents from Foci is constant and equal to square of semi-minor axis and lies on auxiliary circle, but that leads me nowhere.

**Note** There are many solutions available on internet, but they all did this with the same method of taking axis of ellipse parallel to coordinate axis.

**I don't want to do using that method. I want it for slanted ellipse as shown in attached image.**

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: Please also see animation in my post [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889450/extrema-of-ellipse-from-parametric-form/1890278#1890278).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, we try to determine the general form of a rotated ellipse in the first quadrant such that it remains tangent to the axes.  [We suppose it has the parametric equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937259/whats-the-parametric-equation-for-the-general-form-of-an-ellipse-rotated-by-any)

$$(x(t),y(t)) = (4 \cos u \cos t - 2 \sin u \sin t + h, 2 \cos u \sin t + 4 \sin u \cos t + k), \quad t \in [0,2\pi)$$ where $(h,k)$ is the center, and $u$ is the counterclockwise rotation angle of the ellipse relative to the coordinate axes.  (Note I have modified the direction of rotation compared to the linked answer.)

Such an ellipse has horizontal tangent lines satisfying $$0 = \frac{dy}{dt} = 2 \cos u \cos t - 4 \sin u \sin t,$$ or $$t_{\text{crit}} = \arctan \frac{\cot u}{2}.$$  For these values of $t_{\text{crit}}$, we need to find $k$ such that $y(t_{\text{crit}}) = 0$, placing this ellipse so it is tangent to the $x$-axis; i.e, $$k = 2 \sqrt{\cos^2 u + 4 \sin^2 u}.$$  This gives, as a function of the angle of rotation $u$, the necessary vertical translation to make the ellipse tangent.  A similar process using $dx/dt$ gives the necessary horizontal translation, which we show without proof: $$h = 2 \sqrt{4 \cos^2 u + \sin^2 u}.$$  Thus our ellipse is fully parametrized.

The locus of the center is simply $(h,k)$ as a function of $u$:

$$(h(u), k(u)) = \left(2 \sqrt{4 \cos^2 u + \sin^2 u}, 2 \sqrt{\cos^2 u + 4 \sin^2 u}\right).$$

A short computation of $h^2 + k^2$ shows that this locus is an arc of a circle, not the complete circle.

Where are the foci?  We can first observe that they are located at some point along the line joining $(x(0), y(0))$ and $(x(\pi), y(\pi))$, so they have coordinates of the form $$(1-\lambda)(x(0), y(0)) + \lambda (x(\pi), y(\pi))$$ for $$\lambda = \frac{4 + 2 \sqrt{3}}{8} = \frac{2 + \sqrt{3}}{4}, \quad \text{and} \quad \lambda = \frac{2 - \sqrt{3}}{4}.$$  We again skip the calculation and show the result:  $$(x_f(u), y_f(u)) = 2 \left(\sqrt{3} \cos u + \sqrt{4 \cos^2 u + \sin^2 u}, \sqrt{3} \sin u + \sqrt{\cos^2 u + 4 \sin^2 u} \right). \tag{1}$$  Note that this curve gives the locus of *both* foci, where $u$ and $u + \pi$ represent the location of each focus for a given rotation angle $u$.

All put together, we can visualize these loci in the following animation:

[image]

The conversion of the parametric formula to an implicit curve is tedious but not intractable; one would start with computing the square, then show that the **square** of the locus satisfies $$(x + y)(16 + xy) = 64 xy.$$

---

One approach to converting the locus is to note that we can write $$(x_f(u), y_f(u)) = \left(2 \sqrt{3} \cos u + \sqrt{(2 \sqrt{3} \cos u)^2 + 4}, 2 \sqrt{3} \sin u + \sqrt{(2 \sqrt{3} \sin u)^2 + 4} \right),$$ therefore $x_f(u)$ and $y_f(u)$ are roots of the quadratics $$x^2 - (4 \sqrt{3} \cos u) x - 4 = 0, \\ y^2 - (4 \sqrt{3} \sin u) y - 4 = 0,$$ or equivalently, $$48 \cos^2 u = \frac{(4-x^2)^2}{x^2}, \quad 48 \sin^2 u = \frac{(4-y^2)^2}{y^2}.$$  Thus $$48 = \frac{(4-x^2)^2}{x^2} + \frac{(4-y^2)^2}{y^2},$$ and the rest is an exercise in algebra.

Comment: In which software did you do animation?

Comment: @mathophile The animation was created in *Mathematica* version 12.

Answer (score 1):

The method used in the other answer was pretty neat, but I found another approach using the property you mentioned.

Assume one of the foci to be $(k,h)$, and the angle made by the ellipse's major axis with the $x$-axis to be $\alpha$.

We know the distance between two foci to be $2ae$, where $a=2$ and $e=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},$ so the other foci will be:

$$\big(k+2\sqrt{3}\cos(\alpha),\;h+2\sqrt{3}\sin(\alpha)\big).$$

Using the [property that you mentioned](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059564/property-of-ellipse) of ellipse that the product of the length of the perpendicular segments from the foci on any tangent to the ellipse is $b^2$, we get:

$$k(k+2\sqrt{3}\cos(\alpha))=h(h+2\sqrt{3}\sin(\alpha))=b^2=1,$$

as the perpendicular from two foci on tangent $x=0$ is $k$ and $k+2\sqrt{3}\cos(\alpha)$.

Thus we get $$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{1-k^2}{2k\sqrt3} $$ and
$$ \sin(\alpha)=\frac{1-h^2}{2h\sqrt3}.$$
On squaring and adding, we get
$$ h^2+k^2+\frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{h^2}=16.$$
Replacing $(k,h)$ with $(x,y)$:
$$ x^2+y^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}=16.$$